A binary sequence such that sum of every 10 consecutive terms is divisible by 3 is necessarily periodic?
Let $(a_n )_{n=1} ^{\infty} $ be a sequence of elements in  $\{0, 1\}$
such that for all positive integers $n,\Sigma_{i=n}^{ n+9}a_i$  is divisible  by 3 . Then there exist a positive integer $k$ such that $a_{n+k}= a_n $ for all positive integers $n$ (True/ False)
I think it is true .
My Idea :- Basically the question is asking if a binary sequence with sum of  every 10 consecutive terms divisible by $3$ is necessarily $k-$ periodic or not for some positive $k$ .
Clearly if the sequence is zero sequence then the result is satisfied.
Claim : If it is not  a zero sequence then it cant be eventually constant sequence .
Proof :
Suppose the last repeating digits is 0
Then there must exist a 10 length string of the form ..
1000000000 whose sum is not divisible by 3.
Again if the last  repeating digit  is 1 then there exist a 10 length  string of all 1's , again a contradiction.
So the sequence can't be eventually constant
Claim is proved .
Sum of every 10 consecutive terms must be either 0, 3 ,6 ,9 .
So there are exactly either  0 or 3 or 6 or 9 ones and rest zeros in every string of bits of length 10 .
There are exactly 1 , 10C3 , 10C6 and 10C9 strings of bits of  length 10 and whose digits sums are 0 , 3 , 6 and 9 respectively .
Partitioning the sequence into consecutive strings of length 10 we can say
since each of the set of strings with digits sum as a given multiple of 3  is finite in number and the sequence is infinite (not eventually constant) by Pigeonhole principle , at least one of the combination of 10 length string must repeat ..
How may I proceed further ?

Please make the necessary edits as I am facing problem with the curly  braces in set notation .

Letting $S(n)=\sum_{i=n}^{n+9}a_i$ we see that $S(n+1)=S(n)+a_{n+10}-a_n$ and since both are $0\pmod 3$ we must have $a_{n+10}\equiv a_n\pmod 3$, which implies $a_{n+10}=a_n$  .... or have I misunderstood the rules?   This seems too obvious to be what you intended.

Not sure what problem you are having with formatting...to get curly brackets to format use {...} instead of {...}, as with any symbol that MathJax interprets as code.

Since the sum of any subsequence of length 10 is divisible by 3, it must be the case that the difference of these sums is divisible by three.
$$\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+10}a_i-\sum_{i=n}^{n+9}a_i \\
=a_{n+10}-a_n$$
This difference can only be -1, 0, or 1, and because it must be divisible by three it must be 0.
$$a_{n+10}=a_n$$
This shows that the sequence must be periodic with $k=10$.
